# Shadow DOM not shown in Custom Element with Shadow Root when inspected on Salesforce (Rabbit hole)

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to understand how Salesforce have implemented their custom lightning component elements. I've read some of the help docs which imply they're following webcomponents standards.

When I inspect the page:
[image: Salesforce Inspected DOM]

So this looks like typical DOM structure, but when you go into the console and look into the lightning-icon it says there's no childNodes unless you go into the shadow dom:

```
> document.querySelector('lightning-icon.slds-icon-standard-home').childNodes
> NodeList {Symbol(items): Array(0)}

> document.querySelector('lightning-icon.slds-icon-standard-home').shadowRoot.childNodes
> NodeList {0: lightning-primitive-icon, Symbol(items): Array(1)}
```

Now, normally if there's a shadow root and a document fragment it's clearly visible in the inspector as #shadow-root (open). As per the Mozilla example here: https://mdn.github.io/web-components-examples/popup-info-box-web-component/

I also noticed that the custom elements aren't registered custom elements. And SF have implemented their own component library etc...

I'd like to know what's going on? Why isn't the #shadow-root being shown if the nodes are stored there and how are the custom elements being implemented in plain JS so I can recreate.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if there were a page we could go look at.

Comment: It is inside the salesforce application. And I'm trying to learn how to recreate it... So I can't create a sample that effectively mimicks their implementation yet.

Comment: We are currently trying to figure out to use [tag:playwright] to test a custom [tag:salesforce] app that uses [tag:lwc]. How was your experience using LWC ?

Answer (score 8):

Salesforce Lightning doesn't use a real (native) Shadow DOM.

That's why you don't see the `#shadow-root (open)` document fragment in the Elements inspector.

They have polyfilled the Shadow DOM behaviour and the `HTMLElement.shadowRoot` property.

Also they have overloaded the `Node.childNode` property to mimic the Shadow DOM behaviour.

The polyfill they are using is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lwc/engine

#### 3rd party edit

The package [/@lwc/engine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lwc/engine) above is deprecated. But even if the current version might have changes they still use a polyfill. From the [LWC documentation](https://lwc.dev/guide/composition#shadow-dom)

> Since not all browsers implement shadow DOM, Lightning Web Components
> uses a shadow DOM polyfill (@lwc/synthetic-shadow).

Comment: Great info @supersharp. Do you know how I can use lwc to recreate what they're doing? Also do you know if it is possible to undo the overloading of Node.childNode so it goes back to native behaviour?

Comment: @DavidLBatey you want to use it for Salesforce of for another application?

Comment: Other applications. I want to be able to replicate how it works on SF in a test app to see how different technology interacts with it.

Comment: You can install it from npm (`npm i @lwc/engine`) but I don't know if it's well documented. Also I don't know how to force native Shadow DOM behaviour (and why it's not used in SF).

Comment: It would be great to chat/skype about webcomponents and shadowdom if you're up for it. My email is [SOuser]@gmail.com